# RavenDB and email based document id

Tags: email, oauth, document, ravendb

I am following the example for RavenDB Oauth and it seems like the standard practice here is to utilize a user name for generating the id key. This would require the user to input a username during registration and login.

I am looking to have to the authentication based on an email instead of a username, however I am running into a wall trying to figure out how to implement it properly.

I have implemented Oauth as follows

```
 using (IDocumentSession Session = DataDocumentStore.Instance.OpenSession())
            {
                Session.Store(new AuthenticationUser
                {
                    Name = Email,
                    Id = String.Format("Raven/Users/{0}", Email),
                    AllowedDatabases = new[] { "*" }
                }.SetPassword(Password));
                Session.SaveChanges();

                return Session.Load(String.Format("Raven/Users/{0}", Email));
            }
```

which would then allow us the authenticate the user using the following (given that email and password are the only data provided for login)

```
 using (IDocumentSession Session = DataDocumentStore.Instance.OpenSession())
            {
                return Session.Load(String.Format("Raven/Users/{0}", Email)).ValidatePassword(Password);
            }
```

The problem I am finding is that if I use the email as the document id key and the email changes, the document id and any documents referencing that id will all need to be changed.

However, if I use a RavenDB generated id (which would remain static even if the email changes) I cannot call `Session.Load` and will have to use `Session.Query` instead, which is not as optimized if I understand the documentation correctly.

So the question is, has anyone run into this before and (if so) can you provide a suggestion as to how I might accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the email can change, you can't use it as the id.
You would need to first do a query by the id then do the rest using the id you got from the query

Comment: i could be wrong but isn't this a non optimal way of accomplishing the task? Even though the calls would be within the same session, it would still be hitting the document database twice, correct?